# Why are the buttons on computer keyboards called "keys"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

A computer keyboard is a board of keys. Why are these buttons called keys? Is it related to the usage of piano "keys"?

Comment: Hi Ross. This is a general reference question. Please do your own reasearch before posting a question here and tell us what you found. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Key*** meaning *(computing) one of several small, usually square buttons on a typewriter or computer keyboard, mostly corresponding to text characters,* derives from the keys (mechanisms)  of musical instruments according to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=keyboard%20&searchmode=none):

- keyboard:

> - 1819, ***from key  in sense of "mechanism of a musical instrument"*** + board.  Originally of pianos, organs, etc., extended to other machines 1846. The verb is first recorded 1926 (implied in keyboarding).

- key:

> - Musical sense of "tone, note" is 15c., but modern sense of "scale" is 1580s, probably as a translation of Latin clavis or French clef (see clef; also see keynote). ***Extended c. 1500 to "mechanism on a musical instrument"***.

Comment: ***Key and bolts*** : Key has been known from texts since the year 1000. Yet dictionaries refuse to say anything definite about its distant origin. -   http://blog.oup.com/2015/03/key-etymology-word-origin/

Comment: The word [*clavichord*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=clavichord&searchmode=none) (literally key-string in Latin) was around well before 1500, when *etymonline* says the word *key* was extended to mean *mechanism on a musical instrument*, and this sense was originally just used for keyboard instruments like the clavichord. So rather than this usage deriving from an extension of the use of *key* for *note* in English, I suspect it derived from a translation of the Latin word *clavis*.

Answer (score 1):

In my view key is from French clé/clef and Latin clavis from the verb claudere to close. Clavis was primarily a key to a door. French clé was also used for the parts of a piano that you touch to produce a sound. In analogy used for similar parts of a typewriter. Here "key" is a kind of metaphor for a part that works like a key to a door (for opening and closing) and produces an effect as making a sound or typing a letter.

I would not derive key of a typewriter or a keyboard of a computer from key as a special sign in the notation of music as piano key or bass key. So in Etymonline.
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=key&searchmode=none

Comment: Just to make sure: you are saying that the usage of the word _key_ extended from door-openers to musical instrument mechanisms is a calque on French _clé/clef_, right? Not that the word _key_ etymologically derives from French _clé/clef_?

Comment: Yes, I think key derives from French clé and Latin clavis. I think Etymonline's cautious hint at someting like to cleave is very doubtful.

Comment: So you think _clef_ somehow magically was borrowed into Old English _cæg_ (and Old Frisian _kei_), with which it shares absolutely nothing phonetically or phonologically except for the initial consonant? That will require an extremely good explanation. There is no certain etymology for the word, but if the surmised relation to the cleaving root is dubious (it is), any development that involves randomly dropping the /l/, changing the vowel, dropping the /f/, and adding a /j/ is completely impossible.

Comment: I don't think that it is so imposible. If l drops out you have French / ke: / which would become /kei/ . Doris Day sings Que sara as /kei/ and why not /ki:/.  The problem is the reduction of /kl/ to something simpler. And I have the impression that /kl/ at the beginning of a word is sometimes reduced.

Comment: Greek klinein gives German lehnen and English lean. And I think that to jam is related to German klemmen. I said "I think", I didn't say that I can  give a proof. It is my view, but I didn't study the matter. It would be necessary to study Norman-French and for historical studies of Norman-French, Frisian etc I don't have the means.

Comment: But you don't have French /ke:/. You have Old French /klef/. The final f was not lost until much later, and the vowel in English was originally /a/, not /ei/ or /i:/. From Old French /klef/ to Old English /kaj/ is a _long_ way. And Greek _κλίνειν_, while from the same root, does not ‘give’ _lean_. The change from _*kl-_ to _*hl-_ happened in Proto-Germanic, long before Old French even existed. It's not a reduction of /kl/, but the regular outcome of Grimm’s Law. There is no parallel for Old English (or Old French) reducing /kl-/ to /k-/ that I'm aware of.

Comment: I just remember another reduction of /kl/. In Spanish kl at the beginning is generally reduced and in Italian Latin clavis becomes chiave. Maybe key was influenced by the Italian form as Italian music had some influence in other countries.

Comment: Indeed, _key_ from _chiave_ is more believable than from _clef_, though I don't know when /kl/ -> /kj/ happened in Italian, and so if it is possible historically.

Comment: They more I read about key the more I see the connection between key and clavis is problematic. Janus sees the matter from the view of historical sound change. My view is that clavis is in Italian, French, German (Schlüsses from Latin ex+cludere, the same word family), why should English have another word family. Even Old English caege might be connected with Latin clavicula, the diminutive form. The g of caege has a dot, I think it means g becomes /j/.

Comment: One possible reason why the l in OE caeg/caege might be lacking is because it was in collision with OE  claeg which gives clay in mod. English. Just an idea.