# What is the etymology of the sense of 'key' in 'key a surface', 'provides a key for the paint'

Tags: meaning, etymology

The sense of the word 'key' I'm referring to is illustrated in the following sentences taken from the internet:

> - *Would a thorough abrasion with a wire brush suffice to key the surface?* [verb; spelling corrected]
> - ... *use a light sandpaper all over the surface of the door to create a key for the paint to stick to ...* [noun]

I'd define the verb as 'roughen a surface with say medium fine sandpaper to provide better adhesion for say a primer coat'.

[The Online Etymological Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/key) provides a clue to the origin of the usage:

> - [key] ... The meaning "to scratch (a car's paint job) with a metal key" is recorded by 1986.

But I suspect the usage was in use before then (I even seem to remember it being so), and with the useful rather than criminal association. Has anyone further evidence of this sense's origin and the rational behind it?

Comment: The relevant full OED definition III.15 is *The part of a first coat of plaster on a wall which passes between the laths and secures the rest; **(hence) the hold** which plaster has on a surface; the roughness of a surface which enables plaster or some other material to adhere to it,* first cited use 1813. Read that in conjunction with the earlier definition III.14c (first cited 1659): *An instrument which **grips or fits** the head of a screw, bolt, nut, etc., so that it may be turned; an instrument or component which opens or closes a valve.* All about ***holding/sticking*** things together.

Comment: I assume essentially the same "locking, holding together, gripping" sense applies to "keystones" in architectural contexts. Speculating even more (without actually *researching*), I assume something like a ***key concept*** is one which "binds, coordinates" other relevant elements.

Comment: You can also water down emulsion paint for the first coat on newly-plastered walls, to provide a "key" or "sizing" coat (it tends to peel off if you apply emulsion paint directly onto new plaster). I'd say that's more about "stickiness" than "roughness", but in both cases, the key concept is "grip".

Comment: It should be noted that it's fairly common for someone who is irritated with where a car is parked, or something else about how the car has been operated in a parking lot or some such might "key" the car-- drag a key or other metal object along the surface of the car to create a scar of sorts.

Comment: @HotLicks: I think it's potentially misleading to cite "keying" a car here. The vandal who keys your car does so ***using a key***, because that's often the best implement he has to hand to express jealous resentment by damaging your car. He's certainly not thinking *"That'll help the resprayed paint to stick to the car better".*

Comment: Okay, it's about the holes, or slots (or just texture). For example, gypsum needs a toehold, so to speak, b/c it doesn't suction to the wall like lime plaster would. I can't link the sources for some reason; oldhouseonline.com via Wikipedia *Lath and plaster* under *Historical transition.*

Comment: See *key(s)* under *Lath* https://www.oldhouseonline.com/repairs-and-how-to/repairing-historic-flat-plaster-walls-ceilings/

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- What makes you think that "keying" isn't often done to damage the car finish??  I've rarely heard of any other reason.

Comment: There are two subsenses in play, as I said, 'with ... useful rather [/] criminal association'; the one usage seems not to have led to the other, as the 'surface preparation' usage predates cars and car keys..

Comment: @HotLicks: I never suggested ***keying*** isn't often used in that sense. I've suffered the indignity *twice* over the decades - on both occasions with relatively old low-value cars, so the mindless vandals never even had jealousy as a shred of "justification". So I've moaned about it a *lot*. I just meant *that* sense is a modern "verbification of a noun" with no meaningful connection to the etymological origins connecting keys for locks, keystones, key concepts, etc. to keying coats before applying further layers (of paint, plaster, or whatever). Which is what the OP is concerned with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This derives from many other senses of *key* as referring to an object or method used to join two things together, of which they keystone in an arch might be the best-known.

The OED gives one meaning of the verb *key*:

> 2.b. To cause (plaster) to adhere to laths. In later use also more generally: to cause (a substance) to adhere to a surface.

This goes back to 1837 for plaster, while an example from 1923 relates to enamel.

The use of the verb derives from a slightly older use as a noun in the same context, dating back to 1813:

> III.15. The part of a first coat of plaster on a wall which passes between the laths and secures the rest; (hence) the hold which plaster has on a surface; the roughness of a surface which enables plaster or some other material to adhere to it.

This links to many other senses of "key" for something used to lock two parts together.

> III.12.a. 1434– *Mechanics*. A piece of wood or metal which is inserted between other pieces to hold them or tighten them; a pin, bolt, or wedge inserted into a hole, or between parts, so as to lock parts together; spec. one for connecting a shaft to a rotating part of a machine.

From the late 18th century in joinery a meaning of "key" was a piece of wood attached as a reinforcement, which is related to this. And in bookbinding from 1818 "A U- or H-shaped or slotted piece used to secure the bands of a book in a sewing press or sewing frame." So there are many examples of using "key" to mean something used to join or secure things, provide reinforcement, etc.

All of these go back ultimately to the sense of a key as a wooden or metal object used to close and open a lock, which is found in Old English. The use of key to mean a central stone in an arch goes back to 1339, the key or keystone both looking a little like a key (often a long thin peg) and serving the function of locking the two halves together. The resemblance between something uniting two halves of an arch and linking coating to underlying surface should be plain.

There are similar questions about [the keys of an organ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/613784/on-the-origins-of-the-use-of-key-or-clavis-to-refer-to-the-keys-of-an-organ) and [the keys of a computer keyboard](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256681/why-are-the-buttons-on-computer-keyboards-called-keys) which may be of interest.

- Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “key (v.),” September 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/5615315946.
- Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “key (n.1 & adj.),” December 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/2430738253.

Comment: I went to the full (paywalled) OED. They have first citation **1813** for definition III.15: *After the plaster has been put by in this method, it is crossed all over with the end of a lath which has the effect of giving a **key or tie** to the finishing coats.*

Comment: I don't think *keystone* has much to do with it, if anything. It seems more about making a surface grippable; i.e., *keying* a surface so it will have *keys* ready to accept *keys.* It's complicated…or a free for all.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs: For reasons I don't understand, my answer citing the relevant bits of the paywalled full OED has been deleted. But it seems clear to me that the *oldest* sense of "key" (through Latin "clavis") primarily related to ***locking / holding** in place*. But also very old is their definition III.14c *An instrument which **grips** or fits the head of a screw, bolt, nut, etc., so that it may be turned; an instrument or component which opens or closes a valve.* That's *immediately before* the ***first coat*** definition III.15. It's all about locking / gripping / holding /...

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes, I think it's back up now. Thanks. Something was happening that day. I could barely make a comment or link a source; so odd.